Sound not working in Ubuntu 24 LTS
I have PipeWire 1.0.5, but the audio is not working on my laptop (Infinix Y1, Intel i3 10th gen). The output is very low or unable to hear, but it works fine with earphones.
Please help. I am new to Linux. It's an Intel Ice Lake soundcard.
